# sort array in javascript base on the external id

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I have an array of users and each user has a unique id. I want to sort this array by comparing with my `currentUser` so I can have my current user in the first place inside the array and all others after that(alphabetically)
how can I do that in javascript?

Thanks

```
const currentuser = "f8a0b09c-ea3e-4f33-9c01-c16200f6ce1b";

const lists = [
  {
    "name": "Mahdieh Hosseiny",
    "avatar": "/static/media/defaultAvatar.95bdd942.svg",
    "id": "eb6433d3-11e8-4660-82fa-3f53cca569f4"
  },
  {
    "name": "Ahmad Dehnavi",
    "avatar": "/static/media/defaultAvatar.95bdd942.svg",
    "id": "dc21291c-34bc-4363-b733-cbc405ba2eab"
  },
  {
    "name": "Staff 4 Worrell",
    "avatar": "/static/media/defaultAvatar.95bdd942.svg",
    "id": "a3738c05-d6fb-4fb2-90ef-98d0b71939c5"
  },
  {
    "name": "Amir Hossein",
    "avatar": "/static/media/defaultAvatar.95bdd942.svg",
    "id": "c1a70e04-992e-4509-8271-29efe3f6813b"
  },
  {
    "name": "Hormoz Javadi",
    "avatar": "/static/media/defaultAvatar.95bdd942.svg",
    "id": "c9dbbb02-7179-4137-87df-f080cd5b7400"
  },
  {
    "name": "westscityclub verify",
    "avatar": "/static/media/defaultAvatar.95bdd942.svg",
    "id": "25b93407-7b0d-4639-a758-0c7e40a88dc4"
  },
  {
    "name": "Tina  Worrell",
    "avatar": "savatar.jpg",
    "id": "f8a0b09c-ea3e-4f33-9c01-c16200f6ce1b"
  }
]
```

Comment: `lists.sort(function(u1,u2) {  return u1.id == currentUser  ? -1: 0; })`

Comment: Do you mean you want Tina first then the rest sorted by id asc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will ouput the result array in which the correspoding object will be the first, and others will be sorted by `name` prop:

```
[
  ...lists.filter((item) => item.id === currentuser),
  ...lists.filter((item) => item.id !== currentuser).sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name)),
]
```

```js
const currentuser = "f8a0b09c-ea3e-4f33-9c01-c16200f6ce1b";

const lists = [
  {
    "name": "Mahdieh Hosseiny",
    "avatar": "/static/media/defaultAvatar.95bdd942.svg",
    "id": "eb6433d3-11e8-4660-82fa-3f53cca569f4"
  },
  {
    "name": "Ahmad Dehnavi",
    "avatar": "/static/media/defaultAvatar.95bdd942.svg",
    "id": "dc21291c-34bc-4363-b733-cbc405ba2eab"
  },
  {
    "name": "Staff 4 Worrell",
    "avatar": "/static/media/defaultAvatar.95bdd942.svg",
    "id": "a3738c05-d6fb-4fb2-90ef-98d0b71939c5"
  },
  {
    "name": "Amir Hossein",
    "avatar": "/static/media/defaultAvatar.95bdd942.svg",
    "id": "c1a70e04-992e-4509-8271-29efe3f6813b"
  },
  {
    "name": "Hormoz Javadi",
    "avatar": "/static/media/defaultAvatar.95bdd942.svg",
    "id": "c9dbbb02-7179-4137-87df-f080cd5b7400"
  },
  {
    "name": "westscityclub verify",
    "avatar": "/static/media/defaultAvatar.95bdd942.svg",
    "id": "25b93407-7b0d-4639-a758-0c7e40a88dc4"
  },
  {
    "name": "Tina  Worrell",
    "avatar": "savatar.jpg",
    "id": "f8a0b09c-ea3e-4f33-9c01-c16200f6ce1b"
  }
];

console.log([
 ...lists.filter((item) => item.id === currentuser),
  ...lists.filter((item) => item.id !== currentuser).sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name)),
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use Array.sort() method. It accepts function that will be used to sort items. What is worth mentioning it will sort array in place (after calling it list will stay sorted, it does not copy it):

```js
const currentuser = "f8a0b09c-ea3e-4f33-9c01-c16200f6ce1b";

const lists = [
  {
    "name": "Mahdieh Hosseiny",
    "avatar": "/static/media/defaultAvatar.95bdd942.svg",
    "id": "eb6433d3-11e8-4660-82fa-3f53cca569f4"
  },
  {
    "name": "Ahmad Dehnavi",
    "avatar": "/static/media/defaultAvatar.95bdd942.svg",
    "id": "dc21291c-34bc-4363-b733-cbc405ba2eab"
  },
  {
    "name": "Staff 4 Worrell",
    "avatar": "/static/media/defaultAvatar.95bdd942.svg",
    "id": "a3738c05-d6fb-4fb2-90ef-98d0b71939c5"
  },
  {
    "name": "Tina  Worrell",
    "avatar": "savatar.jpg",
    "id": "f8a0b09c-ea3e-4f33-9c01-c16200f6ce1b"
  },
  {
    "name": "Amir Hossein",
    "avatar": "/static/media/defaultAvatar.95bdd942.svg",
    "id": "c1a70e04-992e-4509-8271-29efe3f6813b"
  },
  {
    "name": "Hormoz Javadi",
    "avatar": "/static/media/defaultAvatar.95bdd942.svg",
    "id": "c9dbbb02-7179-4137-87df-f080cd5b7400"
  },
  {
    "name": "westscityclub verify",
    "avatar": "/static/media/defaultAvatar.95bdd942.svg",
    "id": "25b93407-7b0d-4639-a758-0c7e40a88dc4"
  }
]


function compare(a, b) {
   if (a.id == currentuser) return -1
   if (b.id == currentuser) return 1
   return a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
}

lists.sort(compare) //from now lists is sorted.

console.dir(lists.map(s => s.name))
```

Answer (score 1):

you want your `currentuser` element at first position. so one way is to use custom sorting of array. see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) how `sort` function works.

```
lists.sort(function(u1,u2) { return u1.id == currentuser ? -1: u1.id.localCompare(u2.id); });
```

Comment: your solutions does not sort rest array :(.

Comment: My bad.. I thought he wants only his user at 0 index.

Comment: @Scalway thank you for finding bug in my code. Updated my answer